# How to run and view a probit regression in python

Tags: dataframe, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I want to run a probit regression on python.

I have tried running a probit model using statsmodels. Following is the line of code that I executed. I cannot see my results, however. I also wanted to know if the way I am running it is correct or not.

```py
import statsmodels
statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit(labf_part, ind_var_probit )
result_3 = statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit
print(result_3.summary())
```

Here, labf_part is a 1D array of 1/0 depending on whether a woman is/isn't in the labor force. ind_var_probit consists of 20 independent variables.

This gives me an attribute error:
AttributeError: type object 'Probit' has no attribute 'summary'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
import statsmodels
result_3 = statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit(labf_part, ind_var_probit )
print(result_3.summary())
```